# Redirect back and keeping previously entered values

Tags: php

I want to redirect back to form and keeping my previously entered values, Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any library such as Zend Framework to generate the form? This would make it a lot easier. Otherwise, regardless of whether you pass the form values in the query string of the redirect, or store them as session variables or whatever else, you will need to manually check for them on the form page and manually populate each input.

Comment: @LinusR No, I did not using Zend Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use seesions to do that, so inside your process.php file:

```
    session_start();
    //assign all posted values to a session
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION['your_form'][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    header('Location: your_form.php');
```

Now inside your_form.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['your_form']) && !empty($_SESSION['your_form'])) {
        $form_data = $_SESSION['your_form'];
        unset($_SESSION['your_form']);
    }
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="process.php">
        <input type="text" name="txt1" value="<?=$form_data['your_form']['txt1']?>" />
        <input type="text" name="txt2" value="<?=$form_data['your_form']['txt2']?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit Form" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Shoud I use start_seesions() in above codes?

Comment: Of course, sorry I forgot it. Edit: Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code according your post but still can't keeping previously entered.

Comment: If you remove unset() then every time you open the page you will have a form filled untill the end of the session.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake before, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method='POST' action='back_to_your_form.php' name='thisForm'>

<?php foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { ?>

  <input name='<?php echo $key; ?>' value='<?php echo $value; ?>' type='hidden'>

<?php } ?>

  <input name='redirected' type='hidden'>
</form>

<script language='javascript'>
  document.thisForm.submit();
</script>
```

In Manolis answer, you store the needed data in your session, works fine, but unset the data after you insert it into your form.
Here you generate a new form, fill the input hidden input fields and submit to your page before via POST method.
On your page, try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['redirected'])) {
?>
  <input name="key1" value="<?php echo $_POST['key1']; ?>" >
  <input name="key2" value="<?php echo $_POST['key2']; ?>" >
  <button>Submit</button>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here you fill the values back into your form, if you riderected back to this page  you can get this informaten by checking if $_POST['redirected'] is set.
You can make this check global, like I do here or on every input field.

```
<input name="key" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['redirected')) { echo $_POST['key']; } ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

which method do you use in your form GET or

PHP isn't able to just redirect back, generate a form, enter hidden input fields with the names and values and than:

```
document.nameOfForm.submit();
```

Comment: +1, could you please make more details?